# Add android dependency to module in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

How do I add android dependency to a module in Android Studio? Is there a simpler way than manually copying the android.jar?

Comment: Did you work with gradle before? Look up Dependency Management.

Comment: there should be no reason to manually add the android.jar as a dependency. The default project setup applies the "com.android.application" plugin which internally uses android dependencies already (which API version depends on the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion you have defined). Can you share your build.gradle of your module here?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the gradle version and set it in build.gradle onder dependencies:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "geert.berkers.cartracker"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    //Add it here!
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you do.

1. select your project -> open module settings
2. select your modules -> click Dependency tab
3. click '+' -> select library dependency

then search and add your library. It will automatically add dependency to your project and gradle file.